# Single merchant has multiple products, We need separate chat option for each product using XMPP ejabberd connection

Tags: android, web, xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I'm going to implement chat option in my project using XMPP ejabberd. In my project, we have a merchant to create multiple products (like selling goods). We need to implement each product have a separate chat option. For example, Merchant John has two product like Mobile and Car. Now User Mark Interested John Mobile he chooses mobile and chats. Like Peter Interested John Car he chooses a car and chats. Please give me a perfect way to achieve this concept.

Note: We already implemented one to one chat.

Comment: *Please give me a perfect solution for this concept.* -> If you're asking for programmers help, please share the code. Otherwise, please share an email id where we can send you quotes to have the work done without too much effort on your part.

Comment: @2Dee I need to know is it possible to implement product based chat using XMPP.

Comment: And I need a lot of things, but but I don't go around telling everybody. There is a place for everything, and StackOverflow is for certain interesting programming questions (see the help section).